# Displaying iframe with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have this iframe:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Nc9xq-TVyHI?autoplay=1&start=110&end=119" frameborder="0" ></iframe></body></html>';
```

I need to display/execute this iframe on some javascript/jquery event.
My question is how can I display that iframe with javascript/jquery code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to learn Youtube API for it .. you will get your answer [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) ..

As well as see below Demo Link

```
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/TDNm5/1/

Answer (score 2):

$('#divToPutItIn').html('html here');

Comment: This work for me only if div tag is before <script> tag with jquery code...do you know how to fix so that it works either way?

Comment: `$('document').ready(function() { $('#divToPutItIn').html('html here'); });` might do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

If you have time to learn how to do it right, that is using JavaScript with your YouTube video, then the fact that it was given to you in a iframe is irrelevant.  Simply learn examples off of the [YouTube JavaScript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) Page.  They have demo's towards the bottom of how your javascript should look like once you follow with their connection process.

You may run into issues or need additional functionality with your video if you do it any other way.  I know from experience.

Comment: You are right, its better to learn YouTube player API, I'll check that out